# How to conver this list/ tuple in the following list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert list item in tuple

```
drives_a = [chr(x) + ':' for x in range(65, 90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ':')]
```

Output:

```
['C:', 'D:', 'G:', 'J:', 'L:', 'M:', 'O:', 'S:', 'U:', 'W:', 'Y:']
```

Comment: #But i require this types of output plz Gide me
#[(C:, C:), (D:, D:), (J:, J:), (L:, L:), (M:, M:), (O:, O:), (S:, S:), (U:, U:), (W:,W:),(Y:,Y:))]

Comment: Can you provide your whole code as `os` seems to be undefined.

Comment: @TP7, `import os`.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Are you try to list all available drives in your Windows OS?

Comment: How do you get those drives?

Comment: #My wholde code is
import os,string
drives_a = [chr(x) + ':' for x in range(65, 90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ':')]

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension to easily transform all your list elements to tuples.

```
lst = ['C:', 'D:', 'G:', 'J:', 'L:', 'M:', 'O:', 'S:', 'U:', 'W:', 'Y:']
list_with_tuples = [(x,x) for x in lst]

# output
# [('C:', 'C:'),('D:', 'D:'),('G:', 'G:'),('J:', 'J:'),('L:', 'L:'),('M:', 'M:'),('O:', 'O:'),('S:', 'S:'),('U:', 'U:'),('W:', 'W:'),('Y:', 'Y:')]
```

If you want to get rid of all the apostrophes, can you use a find and replace, or transform the list to a string directly with:

```
string = '[' + ','.join([f'({x},{x})' for x in lst]) + ']'
# output
# '[(C:,C:),(D:,D:),(G:,G:),(J:,J:),(L:,L:),(M:,M:),(O:,O:),(S:,S:),(U:,U:),(W:,W:),(Y:,Y:)]'
```